# Got ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable while modifying tf.get_collection list

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow

Got an error while sending modified vars to optimizer, tried to remove unwanted vars from tf.get_collection
Suggest me a safe alternative to remove some items from our list of tf.get_collection with specific scope

Code:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    restorer = tf.train.import_meta_graph('abcd.ckpt.meta')
    restorer.restore(sess,'abcd.ckpt')
    print('Done')
    var = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)
    new_vars=[]
    for index in range(len(var)):
        if index <7:
           continue
        else:
           new_vars.append(var[index])
```

Error near below line:

```
optimzing_op = optimizer.minimize(optimizing_var, var_list=list(new_vars.values()))
```

> File "/home/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 295, in minimize
>           ([str(v) for _, v in grads_and_vars], loss))
>
> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables

Answer (score 0):

You could try something very similar to what you are doing here, but applied to the gradients directly with:

```
# assuming your optimizer is defined in "optimizer"
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost)  # get list of (grad, var) tuples
my_grads_and_vars = []
for ind in range(len(grads_and_vars)):
    if ind < 7:
        continue
    else:
        my_grads_and_vars.append(grads_and_vars[ind])  # filter them
optimizer.apply_gradients(my_grads_and_vars)  # apply filtered gradients
```

That said, it's possible you have some operation in your graph that prevents you from getting gradients. Without a minimal example illustrating the problem, I can't be sure.

Comment: Do you mean grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost,var)?